# Send PHP date to JavaScript date format

Tags: php, javascript, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I want to pass my PHP server time to my JavaScript file.

PHP Code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Perth');
echo date("r");
```

JavaScript:

```
$.get('time.php', function(data) {
  today = new Date(data);
  closing = new Date(data);
});
```

The PHP code returns Sun, 18 Mar 2012 12:01:23 +0800 which is correct time for Australia/Perth. But this returns an invalid JavaScript date object.

When I try to convert it to timestamp like:

```
 echo strtotime(date("r"));
```

I get the JavaScript date Sun Mar 18 2012 04:03:14 GMT+0000 (WET) (this is the value of today js var)

If I use:

```
echo gmstrftime('%s');
```

I get: Sat Mar 17 2012 20:04:30 GMT+0000 (WET).

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: why don't you just use PHP's `time()` function?

Comment: It's the same thing @AustinBrunkhorst today returns Sun Mar 18 2012 04:20:17 GMT+0000 (WET)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The PHP code in [Luna's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format/9755922#9755922) with `echo date` isn't exactly like JavaScript code. This will mimic the JavaScript code exactly:

```
echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O');
```

Comment: That's no the format I'm seeing in Javascript. I see this format: `date('D M d Y H:i:s \G\M\TO (T)');`

Answer (score 13):

You could also just leave the PHP code as it is and parse the date using JavaScript:

```
var date = new Date(Date.parse(DATE));
```

Then even things like this would work:

```
new Date(Date.parse('11 March 2017'));
```

Which outputs via a console log (GMT+1000 is because I am in Australia):

```
Sat Mar 11 2017 00:00:00 GMT+1000
```

More information about `Date.parse()` is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: Parsing unsupported formats with the built-in parser is not a good idea as parsing is implementation dependent and may well fail in unexpected and difficult to find circumstances.

Comment: The link is broken (with a rather amusing 404 PNG animation): *"Not Found. We're sorry, we couldn't find what you were looking for."*

Answer (score 10):

```
$.get('time.php', function(data) {
  today = new Date(data);
  closing = new Date(data);
});
```

What was the purpose of multiplying the string by 1000? That operation doesn't make sense.

This PHP will work for that.

```
echo date('D, d M y H:i:s')." +0000";
```

Comment: It was there to convert from unix timestamp (because of miliseconds) and I forgot to delete. Anyway that returns Sun Mar 18 2012 04:10:32 GMT+0000 (WET) while PHP returns Sun, 18 Mar 2012 12:10:32 +0800. Thanks

Comment: I need my javascript date object to have be set for Sun, 18 Mar 2012 12:10:32 for all the following calculations to work properly!

Answer (score 7):

```
date('D M d Y H:i:s O')
```

It won't work if your current locale isn't English.

A better alternative is to use:

```
new Date(<? echo date("Y, n - 1, d, H, i, s") ?>)
```

Comment: WARNING: PHP returns the months numbered from 1-12, but Javascript uses 0-11. This will always give you a month old timestamp. 

Additionally, one cannot simply subtract a month from the JS date object, since Javascript will "correct" the date upon construction... if you run this code on Jan 31st, Javascript will be given "Feb 31", which it will then correct to be March 3rd (assuming 28 days in Feb).

Comment: Re *"current locale isn't English"*: Do you mean *"current locale isn't US English"*?

Comment: English is a language, not a locale.

Answer (score 5):

Here is an example with the DateTime object:

#### PHP code (works on PHP 5.3 or later)

```
$serverDate = new \DateTime('NOW');

// If you want to set a different time zone
// $serverDate = new \DateTime('NOW', new \DateTimeZone('Australia/Perth'));
echo $serverDate->format(DATE_ATOM);
```

#### JavaScript code

```
$.get('time.php', function(data) {
  var serverDate = new Date(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

A good way is timestamp:

```
echo $data = time()*1000;
echo '
  <div id="setxDatetime">The current server time is: </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var x = document.getElementById("setxDatetime");
    x.innerHTML = x.innerHTML + new Date(' . $data . ');
  </script>
';
```

1381324693000

The current server time is: Wed Oct 09 2013 16:18:13 GMT+0300 (GTB Standard Time)

Answer (score 2):

There might be better solutions, but this one did the trick for me. The key issue is that JavaScript uses months 0-11, while PHP uses 1-12 as mentioned previously.

```
function convert_date_php_js($date) {
    $converted_date = date("Y", strtotime($date)) . ', ' .
                      (date("n", strtotime($date))-1) . ', ' .
                      date("j", strtotime($date));
    return $converted_date;
}

$priceDate = "2016-09-14";
$d = convert_date_php_js($priceDate);
// Returns 2016, 8, 14
```

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was:

```
<?php $today = date("Y/m/d H:i:s"); ?>

<script>new Date(Date.parse('<?php echo $today; ?>'))</script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what was suggested in the 2nd answer. Please, consider reading existing answers and only add another only if it adds anything new.

Comment: @YourCommonSense 

I disagree. Different PHP format that didn't work for me, and `Date.parse` was not being used in it's example.

Comment: It, actually, [was](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42709747/285587).

Answer (score -4):

It is very simple:

```
new Date("<?= date('Y/m/d H:i:s'); ?>");
```

Comment: This doesn't improve or stand out from any of the other answers