# Send date from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have already tried out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format) question but it didn't solve my question.

I have a PHP server which sends a date via JSON to the user where it is then processed by Javascript:

PHP: `'date' => date('D M d Y H:i:s O', strtotime($array['Time']))`

Javascript `var time =  new Date(data.date).toLocaleString()`

But instead of getting 18. January 2015 ..., I get 3. March 5877521 -596:-31:-23 GMT+0:53:28. What is wrong there?

Some things you might need to know: The server has the central european timezone  as well as the date sent. I am trying (above is only an example) to internationalize the date with javascript.

Comment: provide raw data.date value(from console), please

Comment: What is the value of `$array['Time']`?

Answer (score 5):

Why pass a string? JS's date constructor will accept a timestamp:

```
var time = new Date(<?php echo strtotime($array['Time']) ?>000);
```

Note the `000` in there. JS uses milliseconds, while `strtotime` returns in seconds, so effectively you'd be building:

```
var time = new Date(12345678000);
                    ^^^^^^^^---seconds from php
                            ^^^---instant conversion to milliseconds.
```

Comment: then start looking at what `data.date` looks like in your JS code, because there's no way a properly formatted date string would be interpreted as having the year 5877521. or being "negative five hundred and ninety-six o'clock".

Comment: I did: Javascript `new Date().getTime() == data.date` is the same (except for the milliseconds, using the timestamp) but if I do new `Date(data.date)` it is wrong.

Comment: The timestamp in numbers, something like: 1421950569000

Comment: I solved it now: `new Date(parseInt(data.date))` works

Comment: One of my users just reported a similar problem. The server sends a string like "Mon, 07 Mar 2016 17:29:46 UTC +00:00", and the frontend uses JS to display the date: `new Date("Mon, 07 Mar 2016 17:29:46 UTC +00:00").toLocaleString()`. This works fine for me, but my user is reporting that returning a date in March 5877521.

Comment: I believe jamesfzhang's user. @MarcB check [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22March+3%2C+5877521%22) out. It looks like there's a js engine with this bug, and I can't figure out what engine it is. It appears the [Chutzpah test runner](https://mmanela.github.io/chutzpah/) uses it too (which is my issue -- this weird date comes up for any invalid date string when cast to a date in a test, and the test isn't passing b/c an "actual" date (again, this weird March date) is being returned).

Answer (score 0):

I had to parse the timestamp as in Marc B's answer into an int (why ever?):

I solved it now: `new Date(parseInt(data.date))` works

Comment: That does not make sense. If you show the actual JSON I am sure there is something weird, like `date:"      1421950569     "` in which case you can use trim instead of parseInt

Answer (score 0):

First, note that [this error is quite common on the web](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22March+3,+5877521%22&sxsrf=APq-WBtolTGNXLEFx0Ro6PqQURbuFJdZzA:1649449847658), common enough that it's not [just] a "you" problem.

The reason for the weird March date millions of years in the future seems to be a bug in specific JavaScript engines. I noticed the same date appeared when some tests of ours were run in [Chutzpah](https://mmanela.github.io/chutzpah/), a Jasmine test runner for Windows, when our test had an invalid date cast to a locale string and we ran only on its embedded setup from the command line (aka, not in a separate browser).

For our case, it turns out it was [PhantomJS](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs) that was causing the issue. (PhantomJS [used WebKit](https://phantomjs.org/faq) as its engine. I'd imagine your issue was from an engine with a similar lineage.)

Here's a minimal example that causes the error:

in a file called `phantonTest.js`

```
console.log(new Date('').toLocaleString('en-us', { timeZoneName: 'short' }));
phantom.exit();
```

then execute it...

```
>phantomjs.exe phantomTest.js
March 3, 5877521 at -8:-31:-23  GMT-4:56:02
```

You get a slightly date, but are performing a similar operation. You likely have an invalid date coming from `strtotime($array['Time'])` and the user a similar browser engine. QED, etc.