# php date into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime

I have php date:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
 echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O');
?>
```

and javascript/jquery script to publish the date on website:

```
setInterval(function() {
var d = new Date("<?  echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>")
currentHours = d.getHours();
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
currentMinutes = d.getMinutes();
currentMinutes = ("0" + currentMinutes).slice(-2);
currentSec = d.getSeconds();
currentSec = ("0" + currentSec).slice(-2);



    $('#timer').text((currentHours +':' +  currentMinutes + ':' + currentSec ));
},
```

But javascript return aN:aN:aN
How to insert server time into javascript?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send PHP date to javascript date Format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format)

Comment: `Date("<?` must be `Date("<?php`

Comment: Is that JS code running from a js file or a PHP file? if it is running from a js file the PHP code is not running.

Comment: Looks like you got some NaNs (Not a Number) returned. Have you tried to split your script up in parts to pinpoint the where it starts going wrong?

Comment: you should use `Ajax`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `new Date()` as

```
<script>
    function myFunction(obj) {
        var today = new Date("<?php echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s')?>");
        var hh = today.getHours();
        var ii = today.getMinutes();
        var ss = today.getSeconds();
        if (hh < 10) {
            hh = '0' + hh
        }
        if (ii < 10) {
            ii = '0' + ii
        }
        if (ss < 10) {
            ss = '0' + ss
        }


        obj.value = hh + ':' + ii + ':' + ss;
    }
</script>

<input type="text" onclick="myFunction(this);">
```

Comment: Yes. but javascript picks device timer but not server. And server time is syncronized but device is not. That is the reason why i need show the server time

Answer (score 0):

Use the code as follow :

I just replaced `new Date("<?  echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>")` to

```
new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>")
```

its working for me

```
var d = new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>")
        alert(d);
currentHours = d.getHours();
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
currentMinutes = d.getMinutes();
currentMinutes = ("0" + currentMinutes).slice(-2);
currentSec = d.getSeconds();
currentSec = ("0" + currentSec).slice(-2);



    $('#timer').text((currentHours +':' +  currentMinutes + ':' + currentSec ));
```

Comment: When `short_open_tags` is enabled on your server (is on most commercial servers), you could use `new Date("<?=  echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>")` as well (note the added `=` right after `<?`).

Comment: but the same problem with the question asker may be short_open_tags is not enabled with him

Comment: @lord_linus fine but problem the time is static. but i need to show live time. If new Date() then timer shows current time every 1 s but with php i need to update manualy

Comment: @lord_lines - Might be, that's why I mentioned it needs to be enabled. I'm not saying you answer is wrong, just saying it can be done in different ways ;)

Comment: @magic-s - That's not what you mentioned in the question. Please be more clear about what you want to accomplish.

Comment: then replace o (Oh) with 0(zero)

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo in the php date, it should be a 0 (zero) instead of a O at the end of the string.

```
setInterval(function() {
var d = new Date("<?  echo date('D M d Y H:i:s 0'); ?>")
currentHours = d.getHours();
currentHours = ("0" + currentHours).slice(-2);
currentMinutes = d.getMinutes();
currentMinutes = ("0" + currentMinutes).slice(-2);
currentSec = d.getSeconds();
currentSec = ("0" + currentSec).slice(-2);



    $('#timer').text((currentHours +':' +  currentMinutes + ':' + currentSec ));
},
```

See also https://jsfiddle.net/r3b56h2o/ for a working answer.