# How to pass PHP date variable as a mindate to datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

The code:

```
    $minDate=date();  /* PHP date variable
----------
*/

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#datePicker1").datepicker();
    });
    </script>/* datepicker script
----------
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$("#datePicker1").datepicker({minDate: "<?php echo $minDate;?>"});
```

The condition is you should use both PHP and JavaScript code in same .php file.

Also it seems like you just want to set minDate as today, so just use:

```
$("#datePicker1").datepicker({minDate: 0});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using jQuery UI, you should set it up like this:

```
$( "#datePicker1" ).datepicker({ minDate:  "<?php print mindate ?>"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#datePicker1").datepicker({minDate: <?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O'); ?>});
```

It was found in Stack Overflow question *[Send PHP date to JavaScript date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format)*.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a pure JavaScript function, but try it.

[Working](http://jsfiddle.net/Fa8Xx/4497/) Demo

**JavaScript**

```
 $("#datepicker").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        $("#datepicker2").datepicker('option', 'minDate', dateText);
    }
});
$("#datepicker2").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
<p>Date 1: <input id="datepicker" type="text"></p>
<p>Date 2: <input id="datepicker2" type="text"></p>
</div><!-- End demo -->
```