# How to convert PHP date into Javascript Date?

Tags: javascript, php, date

I have a column `start_date` in my database which is of type `date`, now i am trying to pass this data into my javascript function but it returns other data. I tried this: [Send PHP date to JavaScript date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format)
 but it doesn't work on my case. My data looks like `2019-11-21` and my function gives me this `Thu Jan 01 1987 03:00:00 GMT+1000` which is very far from my actual data. This is my javascript function:

```
function manageActionType(action, start_date){
    console.log(new Date(Date.parse(start_date)));
}
```

Comment: don't forget to quote the `start_date` when passing it to your javascript `Date` functions as it is a string

Comment: I already have this on my html: ```<input name="action_type" type="radio" id="stepa" value="Step A" onclick="manageActionType('Step A', {{ $process->start_date }})" required />```

Comment: There are no quotes around the PHP variable. Would be more like `onclick="manageActionType('Step A', '{{ $process->start_date }}')"` ~ notice quotes around php variable!!

Comment: Also see [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) as "2019-11-21" will be parsed as UTC. The use of *Date.parse* is redundant, `new Date(start_date)` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the stated date `2019-11-21` as a simple string variable in PHP it needs to be properly quoted in Javascript - otherwise you will get the invalid / unexpected date that you mention. Consider the following:

```
<?php
    $d='2019-11-21';
    echo "
    let d1=$d;
    let d2='$d';";
?>
console.info( new Date( Date.parse( d1 ) ) );
console.info( new Date( Date.parse( d2 ) ) );
```

```js
 let d1=2019-11-21;
 let d2='2019-11-21';
 
 console.info( new Date( Date.parse( d1 ) ) );
 console.info( new Date( Date.parse( d2 ) ) );
```