# Convert String to DateTime Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have got a problem in displaying PHP formatted date/time string into a customized format in JavaScript.

The date/time string looks like `Monday 21st September 2020`

Anyone who knows how to simply handle this?

Comment: Consider searching before asking? There are many questions and answers to formatting dates in JS.

Comment: Will you please let me have a similar one? I tried, but no success.

Comment: I'm not the one stopping you from searching. This very site has hundreds of questions about JS date/time formatting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9755911/send-php-date-to-javascript-date-format

Comment: @Raqha I have no access to change the API. I have to handle this part in Javascript.

Comment: It would be good to share the efforts made so far. If there is none, nave a go and update the question with that try and the resulting output.

Comment: Thanks, @evolutionxbox . You let me dig into coding rather than googling. I found out a solution by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with - WITHOUT LIBRARIES:

```js
var dateString = "Monday 21st September 2020";
var dayOfMonth, month, year;
[, dayOfMonth, month, year] = dateString.split(" ");
var date = new Date([dayOfMonth.match(/\d*/)[0], month, year]);
console.log("date:\n" + date);
```

The idea is to split the date string into it's 4 parts using destructor, and ignoring the first (day of week).
Extracting the digits from the day of month (with st/nd/rd/th) with regex.
Putting things back into a new Date.

And as a function:

```js
function dateStringToDate(dateString) {
  var dayOfMonth, month, year;
  [, dayOfMonth, month, year] = dateString.split(" ");
  return new Date([dayOfMonth.match(/\d*/)[0], month, year]);
}

var dates = [
  "Monday 21st September 2020",
  "Erich_Kästner 35th May 1931",
  "Someday 2nd October 1967"
];

for(var d = 0; d < dates.length; d++) {
  console.log(dates[d]+":\n" + dateStringToDate(dates[d]));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: I still don't know when to use `let` and when to use `const`, so, at least, I used `var`...